# What is the best Stack Exchange site to find translations from one language to another?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation, languages

What is the best Stack Exchange site for translations?

I need it to be from Hebrew to English; I have a term from the math world I need to translate and I couldn't find the translation in any dictionary.

Comment: Is this only for math-related terms?

Comment: @Jenayah I'm currently looking for a translation to a math-related term, but this is very specific, I will be ok with a general translation site too

Comment: There isn't a general translation site.

Comment: [Questions about where to ask for translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsite-recommendation%5D+translation) suggest this highly depends on the language, but mostly there's not "one" general Stack. Not sure whether one of this is a dupe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) has a couple of questions asking about terminology in different languages, e.g.

- [German for “contiguous simplicial maps”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647694/german-for-contiguous-simplicial-maps) (English to German)
- [German for "Liouvillian extension"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191457/german-for-liouvillian-extension) (English to German)
- [French Question regarding vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495760/french-question-regarding-vector-spaces) (English to French)
- [English term for "Standardabschätzung"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759997/english-term-for-standardabsch%c3%a4tzung) (German to English)

Most of those are in the reverse direction, i.e. from English to another language, but the Mathematics community might be able to help with your question too.

Comment: but this is "from" English. will they accept "to" English, too?

Comment: I think so, I've found another example.